# how to storage old data in react app that updates data every 5 seconds

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, state

I have a react app that shows realtime data that fetches from an API. the data changes every 5 seconds e the render of the app in consequence.
what I need to do is to save a set of scores from the current data and show them on the next update, and so on every time the data changes.
I have functional components so I tried to save them in a state but of course when the data changes it doesn't save them.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can save a history of your API values in an array state value.

Store the latest value at one end of the array (e.g. the beginning) and only keep the number of recent values that you need (e.g. 5). Here's a complete example using random numbers as values:

[Code in TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noUncheckedIndexedAccess=true&removeComments=true&target=99&jsx=4&exactOptionalPropertyTypes=true&inlineSourceMap=true&inlineSources=true&isolatedModules=true&noImplicitOverride=true&ssl=52&ssc=3&pln=10&pc=1#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-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)

```css
body { font-family: sans-serif; }
div { margin-top: 0.5rem; }
```

```html
<div id="root"></div><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react@18.2.0/umd/react.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/react-dom@18.2.0/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@babel/standalone@7.22.5/babel.min.js"></script><script>Babel.registerPreset("tsx", {presets: [[Babel.availablePresets["typescript"], {allExtensions: true, isTSX: true}]]});</script>
<script type="text/babel" data-type="module" data-presets="tsx,react">

import type { ReactElement } from "react";

// This Stack Overflow snippet demo uses UMD modules
const {
  StrictMode,
  useEffect,
  useState,
} = React;

/** Simulated API call */
function getRandomDigitApi(): Promise<number> {
  return Promise.resolve(Math.floor(Math.random() * 10));
}

function App(): ReactElement {
  const [history, setHistory] = useState<readonly number[]>([]);
  const [latest] = history;

  useEffect(() => {
    const intervalId = setInterval(
      async () => {
        const digit = await getRandomDigitApi();
        // Only keep the last 5 values
        setHistory(hist => [digit, ...hist.slice(0, 4)]);
      },
      1e3, // Repeat every 1 second
    );
    return () => clearInterval(intervalId);
  }, []);

  if (typeof latest !== "number") return <div>No data yet</div>;

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Latest value: {latest}</div>
      <div>Recent values:</div>
      <ul>
        {
          history.slice(1).map((n, index) => (
            <li key={`${index}-${n}`}>{n}</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")!).render(
  <StrictMode>
    <App />
  </StrictMode>
);

</script>
```

Comment: ok so in my example I need to show next three events (all the events are in ordered list, once an event is live the next shall be the next three in the list)... so my latest would be the current event (history[0]) and the next 3 ones from 1 to 3 of history array... is that correct?

Comment: [^](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76435558/how-to-storage-old-data-in-react-app-that-updates-data-every-5-seconds/76435801?noredirect=1#comment134778638_76435801) @Velleda Yes, the example shows storing the history in order of newest first.